# Произвольный сегмент вместо CS

Tags: ассемблер

Есть операция

```
mov     dx, cs:Addr
```

которую надо доработать под произвольный сегмент.

```
unsigned DrvSeg = FP_SEG( drvAPI ); // объявление Си
mov     dx, DrvSeg:1c0h // ассемблерная вставка
```

В последнем случае Addr известен заранее. Строка вызывает ошибку Expression syntax. Какой синтаксис верный?

Comment: Не уверен, но может надо 

    mov,cs DrvSeg
    mov dx, cs:1c0h

Хотя, что-то я не помню в асме такой хрени как mov dx, Segment:addres, но, наверное, ошибаюсь.

Comment: Так я тоже пробовал. Первая строчка вызывает ошибку Invalid combination of opcode and operands. Подчеркну, что компилю это в Сишном компиляторе, как ассемблерную вставку.

Comment: Должен быть задействован один сегментных регистров, но не cs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-

```
mov ds,DrvSeg; mov dx, ds:1c0h ?
```

Comment: Да, спасибо вам, так компилятор проглотил.

Comment: Ответ верный (только 1с0h), но похоже этого:
DrvSeg = FP_SEG( drvAPI );
не достаточно, чтобы попасть в нужный сегмент. Связка
DrvSeg:1c0h
указывает куда-то не туда :(

Comment: а что за значение попадает в регистр dx?

Comment: может надо в квадратные скобки взять? типа ...; mov dx, [ds:1c0h] ?